# AS3 - How to calculate intersection between drawing and bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a handwriting game with AS3 on Adobe Animate. I've created my board, functions(drawing, erasing, saving, printing and color pannel) so far. But i need to show a score. To do it i thought if i can calculate the percentege of intersection between drawing and a bitmap image(which is my background for now).

Is there any way to do it? Or can you at least tell me with which function should i try that? Thanks a lot.

Note: Here is 2 images from my game. You can easily understand what am i trying to explain and do.

[players will try to draw correctly(drawn board)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckSsd.png)

[Empty Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEhZA.png)

Answer (score 1):

just a suggestion,
lets assuming that you are recording draw data, a set of points according the frame rate that records mouse positions inside an array.
i used 8 points in my own example, the result would be like this: (6 of 8 = 75% passed)

[image]
<sup>► black line is correct path(trace btimap) ► red is client draw</sup>

---

we need to search whole of the points array and validate them, so a percentage will be gain easily

### how to validate

each point contain x and y, to check if its placed on a black pixel (bitmap trace) we just do

```
if (bitmapData.getPixel(point.x, point.y) == 0x0) // 0x0 is black
```

> **`getPixel`** returns an integer that represents an RGB pixel value from a
>   BitmapData object at a specific point (x, y). The getPixel() method
>   returns an unmultiplied pixel value. No alpha information is returned.

### Improvment

this practice would be more accurate when there is really more captured points during draw, also the Trace-Bitmap must be like this (above image), not a Dashed (smoothed, styled, ...) Line,
 however you can use this trace bitmap in background (invisible) and only present a dashed copy of that with a colorful background (like grass and rock textures or any graphical improves) to players.

### Note

also define a maximum search size if you need more speed for validating draw. this maximum will be used to ignoring some points, for example if max=5 and we have 10 points, 0,2,4,6,8 can be ignored